# SQLite update with 'in' expression on multiple columns

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

The following tables are mocks to illustrate the case I'm having trouble with:

```
master: code | ord
sub: code | status
```

I want to update fields in a subset of rows in 'sub' using an 'in' expression on a join, as in:

```
create table master (code text, ord integer);
insert into master (code, ord) values
    ('111', 4),
    ('222', 3),
    ('333', 1),
    ('444', 2),
    ('555', 0),
    ('666', 5);

create table sub (code text, status char default 'a');
insert into sub (code) values
    ('111'),
    ('222'),
    ('333'),
    ('444'),
    ('555'),
    ('666');

update sub set status='b' where code in (select sub.code from sub inner join master 
    on sub.code=master.code where sub.status='a' order by master.ord limit 3);
```

So the above seemingly works fine, but **what I actually want** is to apply the same operation on tables joined on two columns, as in:

```
create table master (code1 text, code2 text, ord integer);
insert into master (code1, code2, ord) values
    ('111', 'one', 4),
    ('222', 'two', 3),
    ('333', 'three', 1),
    ('444', 'four', 2),
    ('555', 'five', 0),
    ('666', 'six', 5);

create table sub (code1 text, code2 text, status char default 'a');
insert into sub (code1, code2) values
    ('111', 'one'),
    ('222', 'two'),
    ('333', 'three'),
    ('444', 'four'),
    ('555', 'five'),
    ('666', 'six');

update sub set status='b' where code1, code2 in (select 
    sub.code1, sub.code2 from sub inner join master on sub.code1=master.code1 and 
    sub.code2=master.code2 where sub.status='a' order by master.ord limit 3);

>>>
Error: near ",": syntax error
```

How can this operation be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use multiple columns (tuples) with `IN`.

You can use `ROWID`, instead:

```
update sub set status='b' where ROWID in (
    select sub.ROWID from sub inner join master on sub.code1=master.code1 and 
    sub.code2=master.code2 where sub.status='a' order by master.ord limit 3
 );
```